# How to access another controller's action from another controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have just upgraded my Ember application to the newest version, 
but then while testing its functionality, some actions doesn't work.
My previous code which is working fine in older version is below.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
needs: 'sales-order',
actions: {
    showModal: function(mode){
        this.get('controllers.sales-order').send('showModal', mode);
    }
  }
});
```

Looks like the "*needs*" is depreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `needs` you should use [Ember.inject.controller](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.inject.html#method_controller). It should look something like this:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  salesOrder: Ember.inject.controller(),

  actions: {
    showModal(mode) {
      this.get('salesOrder').send('showModal', mode);
    }
  }
});
```

You can find more information in the [Managing Dependencies Between Controllers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) guide.